# Check file size changes before copying.

Tags: backup, robocopy

I need to move files from one directory to another on a daily basis.
`robocopy` seems to be suitable but my problem is the files are made during some time (spectroscopy raw data) and I need to check that all files are complete. There are no specified file size or writing duration which I can use as a condition. The only option I see is checking files' sizes if those are permanent.
Can I use `robocopy` for this task? If not, would you kindly point me towards solution?

Comment: So you are MOVING the files and not copying them, correct? Something like `ROBOCOPY "c:\sourcefolder" "e:\destfolder" /MOV /S` (might change out `/S` with `/E` in your testing). I've never tested it with "in-use" files with the `/MOV` switch. Can you have the "spectroscopy raw data" just be copied to this location once it's done capturing, etc. and have the near real-time files in another location temporarily until that process releases the file or creates a new one to use? Wasn't sure what flexibility you have with this regard so just an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and let me elaborate a bit.
In the source directory will be only one file as everything else supposed to be moved before by script or manually. I need to check the size of this file, say, every five minutes, and move it to the destination folder if file is complete, that is, size is not changed from last check.

Comment: I think that using file modification time instead file size is more useful.

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail
I just do not understand what timestamp file has if it is still writing. Is it actual time when {dir} is called?